# Conditionally change the column headers in Proc report in SAS

Tags: sas

Is it possible to conditionally change the headers of columns in a report by using proc report in SAS? I would like to change the names of the columns based on groups of data in a dataset. Ex: Let's consider there are 3 groups of data in my dataset. For the first group, I would like the names of 3 variables to be A, B and C. For the second group, I would like the names of 3 variables to be D, E and F. For the third group, I would like the names of 3 variables to be X, Y and Z.

Thank you

I have tried to set a temp variable in proc report by using a compute block and then use it in the following compute block to accomplish this task. However, I cannot use define statement in a compute block. Due to this deficiency, I failed. Below is the SAS code, which I had tried.

```
proc report data=x1 nowd headline headskip missing split="|" formchar(2)='_';
    column ("&undl." pg grp subgrp aedecod _65 _6574 _7584);

    define pg/order noprint;
    define grp/order noprint;
    define subgrp/order noprint;
    define aedecod/display "Preferred Term" width=55 left spacing=0 flow;

    compute before subgrp;
        temp=subgrp;
    endcomp;

    compute _65;
        if temp = "AB" then
        define _65/ display "Age <65| (N=&le65_1.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
        if temp = "CD" then
        define _65/ display "Age <65| (N=&le65_2.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
        if temp = "EF" then
        define _65/ display "Age <65| (N=&le65_3.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
    endcomp;

    compute _6574;
        if temp = "AB" then
        define _6574/ display "Age 65-74| (N=&bt6574_1.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
        if temp = "CD" then
        define _6574/ display "Age 65-74| (N=&bt6574_2.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
        if temp = "EF" then
        define _6574/ display "Age 65-74| (N=&bt6574_3.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
    endcomp;

    compute _7584;
        if temp = "AB" then
        define _7584/ display "Age 75-84| (N=&bt7584_1.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
        if temp = "CD" then
        define _7584/ display "Age 75-84| (N=&bt7584_2.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
        if temp = "EF" then 
        define _7584/ display "Age 75-84| (N=&bt7584_3.)| __________________| n (%) [Events]" width=20 style(column) = [just=D] flow;
    endcomp;

    break after pg/page;
    break after grp/skip;
    break after subgrp/page;

    compute before _page_;
        line @1 'Subgroup:' subgrp $122.;
    endcomp;

    compute after _page_;
        line @1 134*'_';
    endcomp;

run;
```

Please see the above code that I am using. As you can see, there are three parent subgroups, AB, CD and EF. Within these three parent subgroups, there are 3 other child age subgroups, which are Age <65, Age 65-74 and Age 75-84. The number of subjects (N) within each age subgroup (child) will change depending on the number of subjects in their parent subgroups, which are AB, CD and EF. I am interested in knowing if I can conditionally reflect this change in N in the output by using proc report.

Comment: Can you share the code on what you are trying to do so that the question is understood better?

Comment: We need more information, preferably a reproducible example [ask].  Show us how your input data is structured, what your proc report currently looks like and your expected output.

Comment: One way to do this maybe using an ACROSS variable that has a conditional format applied via a COMPUTE block. This is guess though based on what you've posed so far.

Comment: @Richard : I was able to achieve this task by using a where statement on the parent group, and then using a %do loop for all parent groups to dynamically change Ns within PROC REPORT. Thank you for all your help.